# Get computers last logon with powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication

I have found the following script, but not able to get the expected result: computer, lastlogon.
Using Windows 10.
For some reason I am getting this error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Variable: 'NTName' found in expression: $NTName is not defined.
At line:10 char:19
+ ... astLogon = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $NTName} -Properties Las ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

And a random number of dates and times:
04/11/2017 07:16:44 04/26/2017 01:08:31 04/26/2017 22:33:51 05/01/2017 07:05:13 04/24/2017 09:01:12 04/25/2017 06:36:43 08/21/2020 21:27:23 01/11/2018 11:47:14 12/27/20
20 14:37:44 01/02/2021 11:24:41 01/01/2021 13:48:16 12/31/2020 14:12:24 01/01/2021 06:57:39 01/05/2021 14:14:14 01/05/2021 21:04:12 01/06/2021 04:37:42 10/13/2015 22:53:5
2 01/01/2015 17:58:55 11/04/2015 04:02:00 06/02/2015 18:46:48 03/23/2011 05:21:05 01/11/2013 23:59:16 01/10/2012 09:46:40 10/16/2015 22:11:38 10/16/2015 22:05:24 04/24/20
18 12:12:35 07/26/2017 13:50:14 04/24/2012 14:22:04 11/17/2014 17:44:11 05/18/2016 13:52:34 03/15/2015 08:52:39 07/21/2016 08:46:35 11/19/2015 06:37:05 02/26/2015 11:50:5
0 02/23/2015 20:03:49 01/22/2015 10:49:49 12/08/2015 14:52:41 02/17/2017 11:05:13 09/08/2015 13:11:49 05/24/2015 13:17:40 05/12/2015 00:51:28 11/05/2015 13:44:19 10/28/20
15 23:28:23 07/23/2015 18:28:34 11/17/2015 17:29:39 10/24/2018 23:43:50 02/15/2016 10:15:05 04/07/2015 10:08:14 02/07/2019 06:07:01 07/26/2016 16:19:09 08/25/2015 12:08:1
9 10/25/2018 05:26:48 03/07/2015 03:30:19 06/10/2015 12:00:27 02/20/2015 10:15:37 08/04/2015 08:48:43 04/14/2015 05:58:17 08/26/2015 16:10:23 02/20/2017 21:02:25 03/14/20
18 14:15:23 08/25/2015 16:45:42 07/09/2015 05:12:25 03/02/2015 13:18:07 04/14/2015 05:37:20 04/22/2015 03:42:14 09/14/2015 13:51:48

```
# Specify CSV file of computer names.
$File = ".\Computers.csv"

$Computers = Import-Csv -Path $File

ForEach ($Computer In $Computers)
{
    $NTName = $Computer.Name
    # Retrieve last logon date of the computer (accurate with 14 days).
    $LastLogon = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $NTName} -Properties LastLogonDate).LastLogonDate
    "$NTName, $LastLogon"
```

Comment: I'd break it down one step at a time. Can you confirm the 'Name' column exists and you're importing the .csv properly. The error is saying NTName doesn't exist. Can you confirm the variable gets populated?. Additionally can you reformat this? it doesn't look right

Comment: @Isaac I got the script from here...I am not a powershell guy myself, just trying to get things done...

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb963613-3a79-4b2d-8ad9-c1c1b0f6791e/computers-last-logon-from-an-input-list?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Have you created your .CSV file. It needs some data to read, that file doesn't exist unless it's created

Comment: Try something like `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,ipv4Address | Export-CSV C:\Temp\ADComputers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8` then your $file line becomes `$file = C:\Temp\ADComputers.csv`

Comment: You don't need a scriptblock for the filter; use a simple string: `Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -eq "$NTName"' -Properties ...`

Comment: thanks guys,this seems to be working.Another issue I have discovered was that the csv did not have a table name.
Any idea how to get logged on data for more than 14 days, as according to the script author, it can only go back 14 days.

Comment: `Get-ADComputer -Identity:$NTName -Property LastLogonDate | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate` this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot and see if it works.

Please note: ensure that there is a column in the CSV with the first block actually being **"Name"**. That's where `$Computers1.Name` references for the computer names in that column.

```
#I would recommend putting the whole file path to your csv here and not just '.\'
#This is the location of your CSV
$File = ".\Computers.csv"

#Here you're importing the CSV into your console and storing it into the $Computers1 variable.
$Computers1 = Import-Csv -Path $File

#Here youre using the $Computers variable  to store the computer names being referenced in the "Name" column in your CSV, hence the $Computers1.Name.
#$Computers1.Name like mentioned above, this is just referencing the column beginning with "Name" (assuming this is where the computer names are)
$Computers = $Computers1.Name

#Here youre assigning the variable $Computer to each Computer name stored in $Computers and telling it to do the following FOR EACH Computer in Computers.
ForEach ($Computer In $Computers)
{



    #Here you're just querying AD against the list of computers with it referencing $Computer as each computer(like mentioned above), and storying the result in $LastLogon.
    $LastLogon = Get-ADComputer -Identity:$Computer -Property LastLogonDate | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate
    # Retrieve last logon date of the computer (accurate with 14 days).

    
    #This is just outputting to your console screen your computer name($Computer) and, the result for your Last Logon query ($LastLogon).
    "$Computer - $LastLogon"

    }
```